# Merge Cells togheter in Gridview in asp.net vb while using a button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have manage to merge the rows in my grid-view with the same values together as the example below shows.

- **Country**----------**Name**-----------
- USA-------------Chris------------
- -------------------Jan------------Calculate
- Africa------------Alta------------
- -------------------Abri------------
- China-----------Lee------------

The problem however is I want the display to look like this.

- **Country**----------**Name**-----------Calculate
- USA-------------Chris--------------Calculate
- -------------------Jan----------------Calculate
- Africa------------Alta----------------Calculate
- -------------------Abri-----------------Calculate
- China-----------Lee-----------------Calculate

The Calculate is a button.. Sorry I can't put in nice images I don't have enough rep yet to do so.

I have no idea how to fix this here is my grid-view.

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>
   <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" CssClass="grd" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="Datasource" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." PageSize="5"Width="900px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="grdalt" />
    <Columns>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="Solid">
    <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" />                      
    </asp:BoundField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="Solid">
    <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" />
    </asp:BoundField>

    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdcalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'
    CommandName="Calculate" Width="150px" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="160px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>

   <HeaderStyle CssClass="grdhead" />
   <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#80FFFF" />
   </asp:GridView>

   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Datasource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"

   SelectCommand="SELECT ID,Country,Name From Table">  

   </asp:SqlDataSource>
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

Here is my code behind.

```
Public Sub GridView_Row_Merger(gridView As GridView)
For rowIndex As Integer = gridView.Rows.Count - 2 To 0 Step -1
Dim currentRow As GridViewRow = gridView.Rows(rowIndex)
Dim previousRow As GridViewRow = gridView.Rows(rowIndex + 1)
For i As Integer = 0 To currentRow.Cells.Count - 1
If currentRow.Cells(i).Text = previousRow.Cells(i).Text Then
  If previousRow.Cells(i).RowSpan < 2 Then
     currentRow.Cells(i).RowSpan = 2
  Else
     currentRow.Cells(i).RowSpan = previousRow.Cells(i).RowSpan + 1
  End If
previousRow.Cells(i).Visible = False
End If
Next
Next
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
       If Page.IsPostBack Then
       Else
          Gridview1.DataBind()
          GridView_Row_Merger(Gridview1)
       End If
   End Sub
```

If anyone can assist me please will be nice.

Comment: Make sure your for loop isn't also hiding each calculate button cell when it does hits the condition. Set a breakpoint and watch each cell that gets hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I solved it in an easier way I think.

Here is my answer..

Gridview..

```
<table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                        BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" CssClass="grd" DataKeyNames="ID"
                                        DataSourceID="Datasource" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." PageSize="4"
                                        Width="900px">
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="grdalt" />
                                        <Columns>

                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" Visible="True">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Country" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="Solid">
                                            <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>

                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="cmdownvalues" runat="server" Text="Calculate" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'
                                                        CommandName="Target" Width="150px" />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="160px" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>




                                        </Columns>
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="grdhead" />
                                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#80FFFF" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Datasource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
                                        SelectCommand="SELECT ID,Country,Name From Table">
                                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Here is my code Behind..

```
   Private Sub Gridview1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gridview1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim titleLabel As Label = e.Row.FindControl("Country")
        Dim strval As String = CType(titleLabel, Label).Text
        Dim title As String = ViewState("title")
        If title = strval Then
            titleLabel.Visible = False
            titleLabel.Text = String.Empty
        Else
            title = strval
            ViewState("title") = title
            titleLabel.Visible = True
            titleLabel.Text = "<br><b>" & title & "</b><br>"
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```